# Can we use builder to build Gtkapplication itself

Tags: gtk3

I am new with gtk.

Can we use builder to build GtkApplication itself.

using code like:

```
<object class="GtkApplication">
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, but you'll need code that instantiates the GtkBuilder, gets the application object from it, and runs it.

It's more usual to subclass GtkApplication in your code and override its virtual functions, and then inside your GtkApplication instantiate your GtkBuilder.